# Find mean of means using pandas in excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My excel file is set up with data like this:

```
REV     PU LOC      DEL LOC     MILES    RPM    
3500    SANTA ANA   SAN DIEGO   160      21.875
```

Having many (500+) of similar lines of data. I want to find the common pu/del loc and their average rpm's. So, if there are 5 different entries of the above line, I want to use pandas to average their RPM values and then output that as the only value listed with the pu loc and del loc in a seperate excel file. The line I am attempting to do this with is

```
df = df.groupby(['PU LOC', 'DEL LOC', 'RPM']).mean(axis={index(0), columns(3)})
```

Although it does not work, I feel like I am on the right track. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: How does it not work? Are you getting an error? Or an unexpected result? My guess is that you do not need to add `'RPM'` in your `groupby`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the other answer, this should get you close to your expected output:

```
df = df.groupby(['PU LOC', 'DEL LOC']).RPM.mean().reset_index()
```

Side note: is the arithmetic mean of `RPM` really what you need, or would it make more sense to *weight* mean RPM by the number of miles covered at each RPM value?

Answer (score 1):

You should not include `RPM` in the groupby.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but I thought that if i didnt include that, the RPM field would not be included in the new excel file

Comment: You should try the code. It will not be included in the index, but it will be included in the result.

Comment: Also, and this is not necessary, if you only wanted the average of RPM, you could just write: `df = df.groupby(['PU LOC', 'DEL LOC']).RPM.mean()`.